# Mi JCheckBox no realiza lo que deberia

Tags: java, eventos

Estoy creando un programa como una practica y necesito que dependiendo de lo que selecciones en el jCheckBox se dejen de visualizar algunas etiquetas (si elige 3 que desde la etiqueta 4 a la diez se dejen de ver) pero no lo hace.

No hay errores de compilación en el código.

```
    comboNotas.addItem("2");
    comboNotas.addItem("3");
    comboNotas.addItem("4");
    comboNotas.addItem("5");
    comboNotas.addItem("6");
    comboNotas.addItem("7");
    comboNotas.addItem("8");
    comboNotas.addItem("9");
    comboNotas.addItem("10");

  public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e){
    if(e.getSource() == comboNotas){

      String visualizarTxt = String.valueOf(comboNotas.getSelectedItem());
      int visualizar = 0;
      visualizar = Integer.parseInt(visualizarTxt);

      switch(visualizar){

        case 2:
          etiqNota3.setVisible(false);
          etiqNota4.setVisible(false);
          etiqNota5.setVisible(false);
          etiqNota6.setVisible(false);
          etiqNota7.setVisible(false);
          etiqNota8.setVisible(false);
          etiqNota9.setVisible(false);
          etiqNota10.setVisible(false);
          break;

        case 3:
          etiqNota4.setVisible(false);
          etiqNota5.setVisible(false);
          etiqNota6.setVisible(false);
          etiqNota7.setVisible(false);
          etiqNota8.setVisible(false);
          etiqNota9.setVisible(false);
          etiqNota10.setVisible(false);
          break;

        case 4:
          etiqNota5.setVisible(false);
          etiqNota6.setVisible(false);
          etiqNota7.setVisible(false);
          etiqNota8.setVisible(false);
          etiqNota9.setVisible(false);
          etiqNota10.setVisible(false);
          break;

        case 5:
          etiqNota6.setVisible(false);
          etiqNota7.setVisible(false);
          etiqNota8.setVisible(false);
          etiqNota9.setVisible(false);
          etiqNota10.setVisible(false);
          break;

        default:
          break;
```

Comment: Soy nuevo en esto de la programacion

Answer (score 0):

Bro te recomiendo la interfaz ActionListener.

Aqui te aporto mi codigo

```
   public class EjemploCombo{

        private JLabel ac,lb1, lb2, lb3, lb4, lb5, lb6, lb7, lb8, lb9, lb10;

        private JComboBox cm;

        public EjemploCombo(){

          Aqui inicias todos los labels y el combo y los agregas a tu combo.

          No te olvides de agregarle el Evento a tu combo.


       }

       La parte de la Accion de tu combo es lo importante, aqui te lo muestro!

       private class EventoCombo implements ActionListener{

            private Object recurso;

            private void ActionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

            recurso = e.getSource();

            ac = cm.getSelectedItem();

            if(recurso.equals(cm)){

              if(ac.equals(3)){

                Aqui pones el texto en blanco de los demas labels del 4 al 10, con el 
                metodo setText("");

             }

           }

        }

    }
```

ESPERO TE AYUDE MI CODIGO BROTHER. UN SALUDO!